# Doubt in a question on cleavage of ethers (Solomons Practice problem 11.18)

Tags: organic-chemistry, ethers

I have reffered to the mechanism shown in the text which is:
[image: Mechanism as shown in textbook]

But I am not able to figure out how this took place:
[image: Actual question.]

Please help me with it. Though it is a homework question but I have tried my best to solve it and so I request you not to report this as homework question.
Thank you.

Comment: Relative (thermodynamic) stability of carbacations, as a second hint.

Comment: I also agree that this product is more stable; but here, Sn2 takes place so how can rearrangement take place? (Or correct me if it's not Sn2 as it is not mentioned in the book.)

Comment: It might depend on the reaction conditions; my initial thought involved a Sn1 mechanism. Frankly, I'm hesitant for `@Waylander`'s suggest of a leaving MeCl; this because right now I do not recall an example (so it is my lacuna ...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all driven by the steric hindrance around the protonated methyl ether.

First step - protonation of the oxygen, clear enough?

Second step - attack of chloride ion: the oxygen of the protonated species is in a hindered environment so the nucleophilic attack of Cl- on the back face is blocked. Instead you get attack on the Me group to give MeCl (which leaves as its a gas) and the secondary alcohol.

Third step - there is xs HCl present so the secondary alcohol protonates. Water leaves to give a secondary cation. There follows a hydride shift to give the more stable tertiary cation which is captured by Cl- to give the prodouct observed.

Answer (score 3):

I fully agree with Waylander's suggest to let the strongest Lewis acid ($\ce{H+}$) and base (the alcohol) react with each other to yield an early equilibrium.

[image]

Contrasting to Waylander, I *speculate* methanol could then leave.  Because of the presence of water (as a proton shuttle), the intermediate secondary carbacation however would give way to the more stable tertiary carbacation then awaiting ($S_N1$ mechanism) the addition of $\ce{Cl-}$.

This suggested mechanism however lacks the liberation of $\ce{MeCl}$ postulated by Waylander; the low boiling point were favorable to leave the system and thus advance the reaction forward.  Equally, the intermediate secondary carbacation drawn by mine could rearrange to yield a 1-chloro-2-methylcyclohexane, or / and 2-methyl cyclohexanol for that in comparison to other cyclohexanes, the formation of both 5- and 6-membered cyclohexanes is favorable.

[image]

It might depend on the reaction conditions if there is evidence for one, or the other, or for both occurring simultaneously.

Comment: If you see the Step 2 written in the explanation I attached, you can clearly see that no carbocation is forming and the reaction is Sn2.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ether_cleavage) argues there are two plausible mechanisms, either SN1, or SN2, which may compete with each other. The examples on [www.masterorganicchemistry.com](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2014/11/19/ether-cleavage/) condense this at one point stating "The Mechanism For The Cleavage Of Unsymmetrical Ethers Is Hard To Generalize" and later "SN1 and SN2 is a continuum. You’ll likely have a mixture of SN2 and SN1 pathways operating." about secondary ethers.  So it is still up to the experiment and its specific conditions.